# Newly loaded elements inherit preset class Jquery addClass

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('input[type=text],textarea,select').addClass('I1_N');
```

It adds class to input, textarea & select. But it doesn't add it to new .load elements. I understand why, but how can I overcome this problem?

I have tried something like:

```
$(document).addClass('I1_N','input[type=text],textarea,select');
```

I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: load that elements with the class that you need.....

Comment: You need to addClass everytime you change the dom.

Comment: you need to do it in the load callback also so that newly loaded elements also will get the class

Comment: Ok thanks! So that is the only possible way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class in callback of load.

```
$(elem).load("url",function(d){

   //d is the HTML
   $("newlyloadedElem").addClass('YOUR CLASS');

}
```

Comment: I understand. I just wanted a cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

you can even use `setInterval` to do that:

```
setInterval(function(){
     $('input[type=text],textarea,select').addClass('I1_N');
         //or
     $('input[type=text]:not(.I1_N),textarea:not(.I1_N),select:not(.I1_N)').addClass('I1_N');
},1000);
```

Comment: Interesting, wouldn't this be demanding on the website for it would have to find all elements and keep re-adding class.

Comment: @MaciekSemik: Now Thats where the OR part works. second code will not add class to elements who already have class `I1_N`